# I am getting an error when I tried to use the following cordova google maps plugin https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: android, xml, cordova, google-maps

The error that I am getting is in the link below .I tried changing the xmlns to xmlns:android in config.xml file. and that fixes the error but after running cordova build android --config.It overrides the config.xml file and the error is back again.Can someone help in using the Google maps plugin for cordova[CONFIG.XML ERROR for Google Maps plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOUZL.png)

Comment: did you added API keys parameters while adding the plugin ?

Comment: I have already added them while adding the plugin Arpit.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing that plugin can be tricky.I found some major issues even after I got it working in my app.
have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/) by [Gajotres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848600/gajotres). 
it doesn't require any plugin.

Comment: Arpit,Can you please give me your email id so that I can elaborate the question in detail? Thankyou. you can email me on sahasraprojectshere@gmail.com